# DataGrid column binding multiple fields

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I would like to bind text and tooltip in each cell to properties of an object. 
The grid looks like this (only binds text):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prop1" Binding="{Binding Prop1.Text}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prop2" Binding="{Binding Prop2.Text}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prop3" Binding="{Binding Prop3.Text}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My data look like this:

```
public class TableModel
{
    public List<RowModel> Rows = new List<RowModel>();
}

public class RowModel
{
    public CellModel Prop1 { get; set; }
    public CellModel Prop2 { get; set; }
    public CellModel Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class CellModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
}
```

Initilialization:

```
TableModel t = new TableModel();
t.Rows.Add(new RowModel
{
    Prop1 = new CellModel { Text = "text1", ToolTip = "this is text 1" },
    Prop2 = new CellModel { Text = "text2", ToolTip = "this is text 2" },
    Prop3 = new CellModel { Text = "text3", ToolTip = "this is text 3" }
});

t.Rows.Add(new RowModel
{
    Prop1 = new CellModel { Text = "cell 2.1", ToolTip = "this is another text 1" },
    Prop2 = new CellModel { Text = "cell 2.2", ToolTip = "this is another text 2" },
    Prop3 = new CellModel { Text = "cell 2.3", ToolTip = "this is another text 3" }
});
```

To bind the tooltip as well, I was thinking something similar to the following would be possible:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop1.Text}" ToolTip="{Binding Prop1.ToolTip}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>            
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Prop1" CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Prop2" CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Prop3" CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But the code above binds all columns to Prop1.

Can it be changed somehow so that there binding works properly?

(Note: I am actually generating my columns dynamically, there are more then just 3 and I really would like to use just one template for all of them).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: All the question is : how do you generate dynamically the columns ? Why can't you generate dynamically the columns style too ? You can define the tooltip in the style too.

Comment: Columns are generated in a foreach loop .I could generate the style dynamically there as well, but I prefer having stuff in XAML if possible. I have found a solution that seems a bit weird (and involves deriving my own class from DataGridTemplateColumn), but works. But this seemed like a simple thing to me, something that should be possible with binding out of the box.